# Failed to install the app on the device 'watchOS 7.4 (18T187)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xamarin, apple-watch

I am using Xcode 12.5.1. I am trying to run a simple Apple Watch App. I am getting this error.

> error HE0046: Failed to install the app
> 'com.companyname.Abc.watchkitapp' on the device 'watchOS 7.4
> (18T187) - Apple Watch Series 6 - 44mm': ???AbcWatch.WatchOSApp???
> Needs To Be Updated

I have tried to find a similar issue on the internet but I couldn't get any. What would be the issue ? Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: "iWatch app"?  Apple Watch app, you mean?

Comment: Yes. Apple Watch App

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue with Xamarin

Comment: A similar issue for Xamarin is fixed by updating the watch project build "Supported architectures" to i386 + x86_64

Comment: @lockstock where to find the project build "Supported architectures"? Looking trough the Project Options but can't find it...

Comment: @klingu in the options for the watch extension project, under 'watchOS build'