# WatchOS app created in Visual Studio Community 2019 not running in watchOS simulator it gives error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019, watchos

I created a sample watchOS application with Visual Studio Community 2019. I create this watchOS application by following the Microsoft guide document [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/watchos/get-started/installation?tabs=macos). Just created a sample watchOS app nothing be added in the watch app project.

It's a Xamarin project

I am able to run the application in iOS simulator but when I make watchOS app project as a startup project then run in watch simulator then I got the following error.

> error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'com.xamarin.WatchKitCatalogDemo.watchkitapp' on the device 'watchOS 8.3 (19S51) - Apple Watch Series 7 - 45mm': ???WatchKitCatalog??? Needs To Be Updated.

I also created a sample watchOS app in different mac machine with same Visual Studio Community 2019 version and get the same error.

Is this IDE bug?

Or an additional configuration required.

and I also tried a solution which was answered by @lockstock [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68205145/failed-to-install-the-app-on-the-device-watchos-7-4-18t187) A similar issue for Xamarin is fixed by updating the watch project build "Supported architectures" to i386 + x86_64.

After trying this solution app is installed in watchOS simulator but but crashed on the time of launch and here is error logs

```
2022-01-28 17:42:44.401564+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=29982
2022-01-28 17:42:44.403030+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: SampleWatchDemoW[29982]/0#-1 LF=0
2022-01-28 17:42:44.479620+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] [db] _LSSchemaConfigureForStore failed with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8411ea49 d46a7df6 9c3567bc 99b71930 ... 9a51d0fc da14e4dd }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xefd64a63 17f6525d 9f91c71a 53a49c75 ... 39c84430 1dd70c59 }}
2022-01-28 17:42:44.480862+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8411ea49 d46a7df6 9c3567bc 99b71930 ... 9a51d0fc da14e4dd }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xefd64a63 17f6525d 9f91c71a 53a49c75 ... 39c84430 1dd70c59 }}
2022-01-28 17:42:44.521030+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=29982
2022-01-28 17:42:44.521684+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: SampleWatchDemoW[29982]/0#-1 LF=0
2022-01-28 17:42:44.530985+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] [db] _LSSchemaConfigureForStore failed with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8411ea49 d46a7df6 9c3567bc 99b71930 ... 9a51d0fc da14e4dd }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xefd64a63 17f6525d 9f91c71a 53a49c75 ... 39c84430 1dd70c59 }}
2022-01-28 17:42:44.531124+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8411ea49 d46a7df6 9c3567bc 99b71930 ... 9a51d0fc da14e4dd }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xefd64a63 17f6525d 9f91c71a 53a49c75 ... 39c84430 1dd70c59 }}
2022-01-28 17:42:44.541499+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] [db] _LSSchemaConfigureForStore failed with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8411ea49 d46a7df6 9c3567bc 99b71930 ... 9a51d0fc da14e4dd }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xefd64a63 17f6525d 9f91c71a 53a49c75 ... 39c84430 1dd70c59 }}
2022-01-28 17:42:44.541649+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8411ea49 d46a7df6 9c3567bc 99b71930 ... 9a51d0fc da14e4dd }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xefd64a63 17f6525d 9f91c71a 53a49c75 ... 39c84430 1dd70c59 }}
2022-01-28 17:42:44.581461+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] [db] _LSSchemaConfigureForStore failed with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8411ea49 d46a7df6 9c3567bc 99b71930 ... 9a51d0fc da14e4dd }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xefd64a63 17f6525d 9f91c71a 53a49c75 ... 39c84430 1dd70c59 }}
2022-01-28 17:42:44.581594+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8411ea49 d46a7df6 9c3567bc 99b71930 ... 9a51d0fc da14e4dd }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xefd64a63 17f6525d 9f91c71a 53a49c75 ... 39c84430 1dd70c59 }}
2022-01-28 17:42:44.581925+0530 SampleWatchDemoWatchOSExtension[29982:412499] [default] -[SPApplicationDelegate _terminateWK1App:]:741: WatchKit 1 apps aren't supported on this version of watchOS. Quitting "(null)"
```

Comment: It's worth checking out the Xamarin Mac/iOS GitHub issues https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+watchos there are several open issues, and this one seems to be a match: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10665 so it is known issue ...

Comment: Microsoft seems not be worried about this issue.
There's a ticket opened as a bug for more than 1 year. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10665